# innerHTML basics

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm learning javascript and i want to experiment with innerHTML. I see that the random number appear briefly, but it doesn't 'stick' i.e. it disappears immendiately.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getNbr(){
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) ;
document.getElementById("nbr").innerHTML = n ;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td id="nbr" width="75%">&nbsp;</td> ...
<p><a href="javascript.html" onclick="getNbr()">get a number</a></p>
```

looking at below tutorial it seems very straightforward so i'm surprised it won't work for me

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Comment: How do you mean "immediately"? You mean after reloading the page?

Comment: when i click the link, in FF i see a random number appear for a split second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyperlink is redirecting.  This causes the innerHTML to set, then the page is reloaded back to it's original state.  If you are developing on a local machine this can be so quick you might conclude it's the Javascript.  (Upload it to a webserver and you should see the page reloading a lot clearer).

Try changing the code to:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="getNbr();return false;">get a number</a></p>
```

The hyper link doesn't need to be set, because you don't want it to redirect when you click it, so set it to `#`.

The semi colons (`;`) in the `onclick` separate the code to be called.  So you can have a big list of function calls for example:

```
"getNbr();anotherFunc();yetAnother();return false;"
```

The return false will stop any redirects or jumps after the functions have run (# href's default to the top of the page which is annoying if you have a long page).

Comment: Thank You all! 'javascript.html' is the name of the actual page. so i should either use href="#" as suggested by Tom or modify my onclick by adding return false as suggested by Shadow Wizard

Comment: Or both!  Removing the .html page link makes the codes purpose more meaningful, concise and clean.  The return false will prevent any unnatural page jumps when it is clicked.

Comment: ah i see! thanks for pointing it out. when testing on a local PC the jump doesn't seem to happen but i suppose it does when hosted on a server

Comment: It will jump if your page is long, and has vertical scrollbars.  Most browsers will jump it to the top of the page which can be annoying.  These sort of behaviours don't need to be on a web server to be replicated.

Comment: @Baba: The most correct think thing would be to not use a link at all (as you are not linking to anything) but to use a `<button>`.

Answer (score 2):

It disappears because the document is redirected to the link `href`. It got nothing to do with innerHTML.

To prevent it, add `return false` like this:

```
onclick="getNbr(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your link is redirecting you to "javascript.html". So the results of your call are lost because the new page loads

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<p><a href="javascript.html" onclick="getNbr()">get a number</a></p>
```

When you click this anchor, you will be redirected to javascript.html page. You can use the following approach:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="getNbr()">get a number</a></p>
```